# How to convert a date time in a ASPX/MVC4 page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have a MVC4 application by using ASPX. In the controller I use LINQ. I read a string and I convert the value as a datetime value. Everything looks okay. The datetime notation is: "dd-MM-yyyy".

But when I see my web page I see date values like 30-07-2001 as 01-01-0001. Why can't the page show the value as "30-07-2001" in stead of "01-01-0001"?

The data-type in the model is DateTime. Then it didn't mind if the datetime notation is European or American style?!

Can somebody help me how to solve this?

In the controller

```
 myModel.ID = myRecord.ID;
 DateTime datum = DateTime.ParseExact(myRecord.Datum, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
 myModel.Datum = datum;
```

In the aspx-page

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<myWeb.Models.myModel>>" %>

    if (Model.Count() > 0) {  %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th width="75" align="right" valign="top">Datum</th>
...
            <td><%: String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", item.Datum)%></td>
```

and the model

```
  public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
```

Comment: Could we see the code that is causing the problem please.

Comment: What do you mean by "show the values well?"  You say you want the values as dd-MM-yyyy, and the examples you are providing follow that format.

Comment: var cultureinfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var date = DateTime.Parse(myRecord.Datum, cultureinfo);

Comment: The string from XML is "30-07-2001". And this string will not be recognized as the right notation for converting to a DateTime-value by using the "en-US" info.

Comment: It looks like either the DateTime value passed to the view is NULL or you are using Javascript to display the model value and the name of the property is incorrect (eg. casing or spelling). Either way it would be interesting to see the actual binding of the model to the view which you have hinted at by ...

Comment: You should not use custom date format strings. Set the correct locale instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have put the CultureInfo in global.asax.

In the event:

```
protected void Application_Start()
```

... and that works.

Thanks for your commands.